# Will Google Chrome be deleted when I install Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I read, that if I install Windows 10, my files won't be erased. But does that mean, that the sites I have marked on Chrome, will also all stay saved or does Chrome gets deleted because of that new browser, Microsoft Edge?

Answer (score 7):

No. Everything will remain the same. Edge would be set as the default but that's changeable (not as trivially as I'd like - you need to go to the default programs settings to change it). Chrome does sync everything you do anyway, so... there's very little risk of data loss there.

Comment: Setting Edge as default can be changed during the install process. There is a "Default Programs" section during setup (after the first reboot).

Comment: I didn't notice that when I set my two systems up. Took me about 2 seconds to set it up correctly, but I felt it was worth mentioning in this context. I'll keep an eye out with future upgrades, I have 3 systems to go.

Comment: You have to select Custom Setup if you want to choose a default web browser. Express Settings makes many Microsoft products the default.

Answer (score 1):

No, Chrome will still be installed and all your bookmarks intact.  Edge will be set as the default browser but that can be changed back.

Comment: Edge will only be set as the default browser if you use "Express Settings". If you use Custom Settings, you can specify and keep Chrome as the default browser during the initial Windows 10 upgrade configuration.

Answer (score 1):

If you have synchronized your Chrome with your gmail account, all your data is stored within your account even if chrome is removed. If you're upgrading from windows 8 or 8.1 without fresh install, you'll found all your data right where you left them including installed softwares : nothing is gonna change.

Comment: You don't answer the question fully.